# Begginger, string in switch in C with sourcecode. Possible?

Tags: c, string, switch-statement

So basically I wanted to create a program in C, in wich you would input 2 character long string (mix of letter and noumber ex.r1,u2,i3,i4,r6) to be the input in my program. Later I want to put this string in SWITCH. Is this possible?
Here's my simple sourcecode. Please correct me on any mistakes :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char string[2];
    scanf("%s", &string);

switch (string)
{
    case 'u1' :printf("%s\n", string);break;
    default   :printf("ERROR");break;
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, switch/case responds to integral values. Fortunately a string of two chars is 16 bits plus the terminator, so you could do some math and convert to an integral value.

Comment: Sorry but i dont reallly understand the term "terminator". Does that mean a = 16+1 because its first letter in alphabet?
Well that wouldnt make sense :D so what is it?

Comment: Actually, @chux answer was exactly what I was suggesting. He takes the string's two significant 'char's and converts them to an integer of 16 significant bits.  As for the terminator, all c-strings internally end in `\0`, which isn't needed for your conversion to an integer. I mentioned it just to save you from implementing a solution that mistakenly factors that null terminator into your integer.

Comment: ...and now that I look at your code again I noticed that you're only allocating a c-string of sufficient length to hold one character, not two, because c-strings always need to use one position at the end for the '\0' nul terminator.  Time to get a book on C. ;)

Comment: Yeah pretty much just what I said. Im learning C, and you guys are helping me to getting better :)

Answer (score 4):

Create a code based on the string and switch on that.

```
#define Code(a,b) (a + 256*b)

char string[3];                   // 3 not 2
if (scanf("%2s", string) != 1) {  // No &
  Handle_Error();
}
int scode = Code(string[0], string[1]);
switch (scode) {
  case Code('u', '1') : printf("%s\n", string); break;
  case Code('r', '2') : printf("r2\n"); break;
  ...
  default   :printf("ERROR");break;
}
```

A `switch(x)` needs an integer value for `x` and `string` is an array.  So the original approach will not work.
The program can use an integer based on the string for `x` and use the same method for generating the `case` values.  Since there is only the first 2 `char` of the string are of interest, the `int` value is unique.

Comment: A primitive hash function. Clever.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Switch only works with integral types in C (`int`, `short`, `long`, etc, as well as types defined with `enum`).

You can however use a simple if-else construct to get the same behavior:

```
if (strcmp(string, "ui" ) == 0) //test for string equality
{
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
else
{
    printf("ERROR")
}
```

We use `strcmp` instead of `==` because we are dealing pointers which almost certainly not compare equal even when the two strings have the same content.

`strcmp(str1, str2) == 0` is the standard idoim in C for comparing two strings.

`strcmp` returns an integer representing how two strings compare to each other. 0 means they are equal, a negative number means that the first string is lexographically "less than" the second, and a positive number means that the first string is lexographically "greater than" the second. More info can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcmp).

Comment: strcmp(string, "u1") you mean? beuause my point was to mix noumbers and letters. Why strcmp tho? and why test it if its equal 0?

Comment: @user2958062 http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcmp should help.

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell That's  a better link than the one I posted. editing into answer.

Answer (score 1):

A switch won't work here.
You need to use an if/else if construct and strcmp to compare the strings.
Also, you need at least 3 characters in your input array so that it can hold the two input characters and the terminating null character.
Of course, such a small buffer can easily overflow.

Comment: Yeah im a begginer. I dont really know what strcmp is and why I should compare two strings? yeah i kind of forgot i should've put [1] but what does it mean It could over flow? do you mean like its easily fixed by puting something like 0u1 instead of u1? i dont really quite get it ;)

Comment: Good point about buffer overflow. Easily overlooked but important. Probably get away with it here because it was the last thing on the stack...

Comment: @user2958062 he means that you only allocated two bytes for your string, but you need at least three (in C every string has an invisble `'nul'` character to indicate "end of string" appended. So "hello" is really 'h'-'e'-'l'-'l'-'o'-'\0' - six bytes long. So do `char string[3]'` at least...

Comment: Okay Floris so if i recall correctly I was right. I wanted to output u1, so that would really look like u-1-\0 and would be 3 bytes long and array[2] seems enought because [3]={0,1,2} am i right?